# MySQL differences between aggregate order in query vs subquery

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have 2 query about ordering data:

Query 1:

```
SELECT  * FROM    (
    SELECT      idprovince, COUNT(*) total
    FROM        cities
    JOIN        persons USE INDEX (index_5) USING (idcity)
    WHERE       is_tutor = 'Y'
    GROUP BY    idprovince
) A
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT      idprovince, COUNT(*) total
FROM        cities
JOIN        persons USE INDEX (index_5) USING (idcity)
WHERE       is_tutor = 'Y'
GROUP BY    idprovince
ORDER BY    total DESC
```

Query 1 return data much faster than query 2, my question is what is big difference between ordering using query and using it in subquery?

NOTE:my db version is mysql-5.0.96-x64. Data count is about 400k in persons, and 500 in cities.

**UPDATE:**
Output of mysql explain command:

Query 1:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    -> SELECT  *
    -> FROM    (
    ->     SELECT      idprovince, COUNT(*) total
    ->     FROM        cities
    ->     JOIN        persons USE INDEX (index_5) USING (idcity)
    ->     WHERE       is_tutor = 'Y'
    ->     GROUP BY    idprovince
    -> ) A
    -> ORDER BY total DESC
    -> ;
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                               |     34 | Using filesort                               |
|  2 | DERIVED     | persons    | ref    | index_5       | index_5 | 2       |                                    | 163316 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | cities     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | _myproject_lesaja_2.persons.idcity |      1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (1.22 sec)
```

Query 2:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
    ->     SELECT      idprovince, COUNT(*) total
    ->     FROM        cities
    ->     JOIN        persons USE INDEX (index_5) USING (idcity)
    ->     WHERE       is_tutor = 'Y'
    ->     GROUP BY    idprovince
    ->     ORDER BY    total DESC;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cities  | index | PRIMARY       | FK_cities_1 | 4       | NULL  |      4 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | persons | ref   | index_5       | index_5     | 2       | const | 163316 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Result Query 1:

```
mysql> SELECT  *
    -> FROM    (
    ->     SELECT      idprovince, COUNT(*) total
    ->     FROM        cities
    ->     JOIN        persons USE INDEX (index_5) USING (idcity)
    ->     WHERE       is_tutor = 'Y'
    ->     GROUP BY    idprovince
    -> ) A
    -> ORDER BY total DESC
    -> ;
+------------+-------+
| idprovince | total |
+------------+-------+
|         35 | 15797 |
......................
......................
......................

|         76 |  2091 |
|         65 |  2018 |
+------------+-------+
34 rows in set (0.78 sec)
```

Result Query 2:

```
mysql> SELECT      idprovince, COUNT(*) total
    -> FROM        cities
    -> JOIN        persons USE INDEX (index_5) USING (idcity)
    -> WHERE       is_tutor = 'Y'
    -> GROUP BY    idprovince
    -> ORDER BY    total DESC;
+------------+-------+
| idprovince | total |
+------------+-------+
|         35 | 15797 |
|         33 | 14413 |
|         12 | 13683 |
......................
......................
......................
|         34 |  2135 |
|         76 |  2091 |
|         65 |  2018 |
+------------+-------+
34 rows in set (8 min 25.80 sec)
```

SHOW PROFILE OUTPUT:
QUERY 1:

```
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000240 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000043 |
| System lock          | 0.000004 |
| Table lock           | 0.000392 |
| optimizing           | 0.000084 |
| statistics           | 0.004455 |
| preparing            | 0.000026 |
| Creating tmp table   | 0.000221 |
| executing            | 0.000002 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.913722 |
| Sorting result       | 0.000065 |
| Sending data         | 0.000020 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000145 |
| Sending data         | 0.000008 |
| init                 | 0.000017 |
| optimizing           | 0.000002 |
| statistics           | 0.000038 |
| preparing            | 0.000007 |
| executing            | 0.000001 |
| Sorting result       | 0.000012 |
| Sending data         | 0.000337 |
| end                  | 0.000002 |
| end                  | 0.000002 |
| query end            | 0.000002 |
| freeing items        | 0.000020 |
| closing tables       | 0.000001 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000074 |
| closing tables       | 0.000003 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000001 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000003 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

QUERY 2:

```
+----------------------+------------+
| Status               |   Duration |
+----------------------+------------+
| starting             |   0.000195 |
| Opening tables       |   0.000029 |
| System lock          |   0.000004 |
| Table lock           |   0.000011 |
| init                 |   0.000078 |
| optimizing           |   0.000021 |
| statistics           |   0.003399 |
| preparing            |   0.000025 |
| Creating tmp table   |   0.000259 |
| Sorting for group    |   0.000007 |
| executing            |   0.000001 |
| Copying to tmp table | 506.711308 |
| Sorting result       |   0.000049 |
| Sending data         |   0.000298 |
| end                  |   0.000004 |
| removing tmp table   |   0.000150 |
| end                  |   0.000002 |
| end                  |   0.000002 |
| query end            |   0.000002 |
| freeing items        |   0.000013 |
| closing tables       |   0.000003 |
| logging slow query   |   0.000001 |
| logging slow query   |   0.000042 |
| cleaning up          |   0.000003 |
+----------------------+------------+
```

CREATE STATEMENT

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
    idperson INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    is_tutor ENUM('Y','N') NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    ...
    idcity INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (idperson),
    UNIQUE INDEX index_3 (name) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX index_4 (email) USING BTREE,
    INDEX index_5 (is_tutor),
    ...
    CONSTRAINT FK_persons_1 FOREIGN KEY (idcity) REFERENCES cities (idcity)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=414738;

CREATE TABLE cities (
    idcity INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    idprovince INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idcity),
    UNIQUE INDEX index_3 (city),
    INDEX FK_cities_1 (idprovince),
    CONSTRAINT FK_cities_1 FOREIGN KEY (idprovince) REFERENCES provinces (idprovince)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Is there any difference in EXPLAIN output?

Comment: I just update the explain and the result.

Comment: @RaymondNijland There is no table with the total column, it's an aggregate computed by the query.

Comment: @bramaningds i need also need the show create table structure..

Comment: @bramaningds and can you also profile your query  with   SET profiling= 1;     SHOW PROFILES;   and   SHOW PROFILE ALL FOR QUERY query_id     so you can see off the query is CPU or Disk I/O bounded

Comment: I've added Show Profiles output, and the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I am admittedly not an expert on this one but looking at [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) on `ORDER BY` **Optimization**, you have not only one but two un-optimized use of `ORDER BY` in your Query No. 2:

```
SELECT      idprovince, COUNT(*) total
FROM        cities
JOIN        persons USE INDEX (index_5) USING (idcity)
WHERE       is_tutor = 'Y'
GROUP BY    idprovince
ORDER BY    total DESC
```

**First one :**

The key used to fetch the rows

```
WHERE is_tutor = 'Y'
```

is not the same as the one used in the `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY total DESC
```

**Second one :**

You have different `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` expressions.

```
GROUP BY    idprovince
ORDER BY    total DESC
```

On the two cases above MySQL will not use Indexes in order to resolve `ORDER BY` although it could use indexes in searching for the rows to match the `WHERE` clause.

On other hand your Query No. 1, follows the optimized form of `ORDER BY` although the `ORDER BY` is used outside the sub-query.

Thus could be the reason that Query No. 2 is far slower than Query No. 1.

Additionally, in both cases the `Index (idCity)` will be virtually useless in resolving also `ORDER BY` because index uses `idCity` while `ORDER BY` clause uses `Total` which is an aggregate result.

See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234057/optimize-an-order-by-query) also.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your respond. 'total' is aggregat function, so it must not use indexes for ordering. Index_5 is index for is_tutor field.

Comment: @bramaningds Could you show profile for your Query No. 1? I could see that your Query No. 2's copying to temporary table has the most time consume in your query.

Comment: Query 1 takes about 780ms, so i guess it will be below 1 s for all profiles. Now, i m on the way and will be home in 12 hours from now. I will update profile output for query 1 asap.